# How to enable automatic Manhattanize mode in dymola?

Tags: dymola

How could I enable the automatic Manhattanize model in Dymola?
I am using Dymola 2021, but I just found how to Manhattanize one connection.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Dymola 2021 (and earlier ) it can be set in Tools>Options>Graphical Editor>Automatic manhattanize of connections

Or by setting `Advanced.ManhattanizeConnection=true;`

However, I believe it is enabled as default.